# how to save the data from database to a folder in mvc application

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have saved some files in SQL table through an application in admin side, but now I have to take back the files saved in the table to a folder in another application to the website. I need to save the files in a folder called MyFiles and want to download the files by clicking on the download link 
   controller

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var Downloads = db.Downloads.ToList();
        return View(Downloads);
    }
```

View

```
@model List<ThaniyamBank.Models.Download>


<div class="row">

        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-12 form_cont">
                <p class="all_sub_hed">@item.ItemName</p>
                <p class="tet">@item.Description</p>
                <a href="http://localhost:56572/MyFiles/@(item.Url)" class="hvr-icon-back">Download Form</a>
            </div>
        }
    </div>
```

this is my folder which I need to save the data from table

[image]

the files shows here is which I have added directly

How can I get files directly from table

this is my table called downloads

[image]

Here the Url column is the name of the file with extension, I need to get this Url to the folder myFiles in the application. How can I get the files from table? can anyone please help me to find the solution, how the working ??

Comment: Use `Server.MapPath` with directory path where the files saved into and file name taken from DB (assumed EF is being used, you can query by `BankEntities.Downloads.Where(...).Select(x => x.Url)`, e.g. `Server.MapPath("~/MyFiles" + model.Url)`.

Comment: But Iam not passing id in action parameter to give where clause . how can it works properly ?

Comment: In table you just have file name. So where is actually file exist? Does it exist in admin project and you want to save it in another your main website project?

Comment: yes. admin ads the file and it also want to save it folder of another application, which is used by users. But I don't know how to save this in the folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing, you need to change `URL` Column of your `Table`. It should contains full Directory path of your PDF file at your Admin Project and add another column for file name.

And in your Action Method, Simply retrieve the data from your table and pass it to view.

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
   var Downloads = db.Downloads.ToList();
   return View(Downloads);
}
```

And at your View, bind File URL to another action link:

```
@model List<ThaniyamBank.Models.Download>
<div class="row">

@foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-12 form_cont">
            <p class="all_sub_hed">@item.ItemName</p>
            <p class="tet">@item.Description</p>
            <a href="@@Url.Action("SaveFile", "Download"), new { FilePath = @item.Url, FileName = @item.FileName })" class="hvr-icon-back">Download Form</a>
        </div>
    }
</div>
```

And in your SaveFile Action Method:

```
public ActionResult SaveFile(string FilePath, string FileName)
{
     using(WebClient client = new WebClient())
     {
        client.DownloadFile(FilePath , Server.MapPath(Path.Combine("~/MyFiles/", FileName));
     }
}
```

[WebClient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You should define your file path by mapping to its server path.
In your action, you can do like this :

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var Downloads = db.Downloads.ToList();
        Downloads.ForEach(x=>{
           x.Url =  Server.MapPath(Url.Content("~/MyFiles/" + x.Url));
        });
        return View(Downloads);
    }
```

In your view side, you can simply give Url :

```
@model List<ThaniyamBank.Models.Download>
<div class="row">

        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-12 form_cont">
                <p class="all_sub_hed">@item.ItemName</p>
                <p class="tet">@item.Description</p>
                <a href="@(item.Url)" class="hvr-icon-back">Download Form</a>
            </div>
        }
    </div>
```

Comment: while giving is code in action, getting error like `List<Download> does not contain definition foe Foreach and  no extension method accepting first argument of type 'List<Download>' could be found`,   why is this error ??

Comment: you need to import System.Linq by `using System.Linq;`

Comment: but it is not downloading and no error generating. I checked using breakpoints and noticed that the Url shows the entire path . I need only the Name of the file ?When I ckilck on the download lik it is not downloading. why ?

Comment: yeah, it returns complete url path so you don't need to specify full url in view section. you can just do :  `<a href="@(item.Url)" class="hvr-icon-back">Download Form</a>`

Comment: Iam getting the path But it is not downloading by clicking the link and not saving the data from table to the folder ??

Comment: what url are you getting? You need to inspect yourself about your expected url and output url.

Comment: Just showing the complete path where is the file locates , but not saving in the application folder, if it is saved , download can be done , but not saving ?

Comment: Sorry,I didn't get you. what do you mean by not saving in application folder? where do you want to display file from?

Comment: I have a folder called MyFiles in the project which I am doing and I want to save the data from table to that folder "MyFiles"

Comment: what kind of data you want to have in MyFiles? As far from my understanding, you already have those files in MyFiles and you just to download data from that folder

Comment: The files in the folder is what i give. but I want it to get it from table , the file in the folder is the name of the file

Comment: You've already got your server file path from item.Url. You just need to make correct link to it.

Comment: but its not saving in folder

Comment: I think, we are not in same track. I don't know, what do you want to save in folder? Please make your post clear.  You should make clear of what you are asking.

Comment: I want to save the data in the URL column which I shown in the question, to the folder called My files. How can this be done ?

Comment: You already have those data in MyFiles. I can see that in the image you posted

Comment: That data is which I have added and not y taking from the database. I want the data to take it from table and add which I have added ?

Comment: I still not able get your question. I think, you need to ask new question